# How to efficiently query object with large field array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, express

So basically I have an object schema that has an array field that will hold ids for objects inside a different collection. This array field has the potential to have thousands of ids inside of it. I have been omitting this field using `.select(["-fieldName"]);` in my queries up till now but I need to include it in my query if I wanna add on to it.

I would assume querying an object with such a large field is costly in performance so therefore **my question is how can I efficiently query such an object?**

I would like to just omit this field in my query but then I can't add ids into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an item to the array field you can use the `$push` operator.

```
collection.updateOne(query, { $push: { arrayField: value } });
```

Comment: Does this still technically query the entire object? Because like I said I omit the field in my queries because it can be very large.

Comment: No it does not. I would suggest you to read the docs of update and $push.... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#mongodb-method-db.collection.update